# starter ruby - my first ruby site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to make my first ruby - based website.

I am assuming looking at tutorials that `print "hello"` should work, but it does not.

Any pointers? I am assuming this is a silly noob question.

my file is located on mysite.com/test.rb

thanks!

(this is more of a dummy starter question than coding, so it is here rather than stack).

Comment: if you are going to vote it down, please tell me why so i may improve it. thanks.

Comment: Your question is considered a non-question, because you're asking a question that cannot be answered without a lot of discussion, and that has no exact answer. How well do you know Ruby? How well do you understand how web servers work, along with CGI and the parameters that are passed to your code? Those are basics you need to know. What is in your "test.rb" file? What did you follow to create it? We need to know those things to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/).  You can get a hello world site up in 5 lines of code, and then start checking out tutorials from there.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ruby on Rails resource http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book. It is very easy to start learning.

Answer (score 0):

If your file only contains the following

```
print "hello"
```

then it most certainly wont just work by browsing to `site.com/foo.rb`

You need things setup like a webserver to handle the request and route it to a ruby interpreter, etc...